# Sort lines in ArrayList by elements inside line

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

This is a bit of a tricky and long question, so please bear with me.

I have a finite number of lines in an input file of the form:

`2015000,Advanced YouTube Commenting,Department of Comp Sci,3`

`2015001,Basket Weaving,Department of Fine Arts,1,`, etc...

The main method sets the constructor:

`FileUtil fUtil1 = new FileUtil("input.txt",1,"output1.txt");`

The `"input.txt"` is the file it's getting these lines from, and `"ouput1.txt"` is the file where these lines will be written on.

The number `"1"` tells me if
I want to either arrange these lines by their `crns` (represented by 0), their `names` (1), their `departments` (2), or their `year` (3).

So the hard part is, I don't just have to arrange these lines in ascending order, but I have to arrange their **ELEMENTS** in ascending order.

My question is; is there a more efficient way to do this than what I currently have? We haven't learned how to tokenize `ArrayLists` yet, but perhaps that's a much better way to do this.

This is what I have so far:

```
private ArrayList<String> memFile; // sorted lines from input file
private int column;
....
public void sort(){

  BufferedReader inFile;
  String readLine;
  // I read in each line of the text file and add it to the `ArrayList<String> memFile`
  try{
    inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    while((readLine = inFile.readLine()) != null){
    memFile.add(readLine);
    insertSorted(readLine);

    }//while
    inFile.close();
  }//try

  catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }//catch
}//sort

private void insertSorted(String line){

  // I tokenize the given line to get each element
  String[] tokens = line.trim().split(",");
  int registration = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]); //crn number
  String title = tokens[1]; // course name
  String department = tokens[2]; // course department 
  int year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]); // course year
  String word = "";  

  //I look at the lines already in the list, and then tokenize them
  int index = memFile.size() - 1;
  String otherLine = memFile.get(index);
  String[] tokens2 = otherLine.trim().split(",");
  int registration2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens2[0]); //crn number
  String title2 = tokens2[1]; // course name
  String department2 = tokens2[2]; // course department 
  int year2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens2[3]); // course year
  String otherWord = "";

  // if the given column equals the token position in the line, then make a new word
  for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
    if(column == i){
      word = (String)tokens[i];
      otherWord = (String)tokens2[i];}
    else{
      word = null;}
  }
  //sort the list
  while(index >= 0 && (otherWord).compareTo(word) > 0)
    index--;
    memFile.add(index+1,line);
}//insertSorted
```

Comment: I think this would be a better question if you made it more specific.  You ask for a "better way to do this" and then give us code to read, analyze, extract the "way" you are doing it, guess what it is about it that you are suspicious might be done better, and propose it.  What part of this do you suspect might be improved, and how is it done now?

Comment: what does it mean arrange the elements in ascending order.  I understand sorting the lines by one of the key elements in the line.

Comment: Why does every line have a number telling you how to sort it?  Sorting by a particular element for the whole list makes sense but sorting each line a different way makes no sense at all.  If the file held the two example lines you gave how would you sort them?

Comment: @faljbour, arranging the elements in ascending order would be say the `int column` was 1, then the following list of names would be sorted as such: Advanced Youtube commenting, Basket Weaving, Paper Airplanes. If the `int column` was 3, then the list of years would be sorted; 1,1,3, etc...

Comment: @CandiedOrange, it's not a different way for each line, but say I wanted to make another list sorting the names instead of the years, then I would simply change the int number inside FileUtil to 3; ` FileUtil fUtil3 = new FileUtil("input.txt",3,"output3.txt");`

Comment: @arcy, I'm sorry for the confusion, I was just wondering if someone had done something similiar, maybe they could spot that I was way off. The part I don't like is having to tokenize both line, and newLine. This seems the only logical way for me to get the elements inside the lines, but maybe there's an easier way? I'm not sure.

Comment: Is the number of elements in each line fixed?

Comment: Something to note - You're inserting each element along the way to keep the list sorted, but because ArrayList has `O(N)` insert, this process is going to be `O(N^2)`. If you just added each element and then used `Collections.sort(memFile, new Comparator<String>().....);`, you'd get `O(Nlog(N))` time complexity.

Comment: @CandiedOrange. Yes, the number of elements is always going to be 4, and of the form : (crn, name, department, year). I guess a better question I should have asked would be how to sort the `ArrayList` by one of these elements, then trying to sort them by incorporating the numbers 0,1,2,3 and confusing everyone

Comment: @Mshnik, Thanks for the suggestion! I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this (especially given that you're in Java) is to create a class to represent the data, rather than trying to work with strings all the way through. Consider the class:

```
public class Data{
  public final int crns;
  public final String name;
  public final String department;
  public final int year;

  public Data(int crns, String name, String department, int year){
    this.crns = crns;
    this.name = name;
    this.department = department;
    this.year = year;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return crns + "," + name + "," + department + "," + year;
  }
}
```

Then you can simply convert each line to a Data as you read it in, perform operations on the ArrayList of Data, and convert them back to strings afterwards.

```
private ArrayList<Data> memFile;
private int column;
....
public void sort(){

  memFile.clear(); //Make sure that calling sort twice doesn't break it
  BufferedReader inFile;
  String readLine;
  try{
    inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    while((readLine = inFile.readLine()) != null){

      try{
        //Read and split the next line
        String[] tokens = readLine.trim().split(",");
        int registration = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]); //crn number
        String title = tokens[1]; // course name
        String department = tokens[2]; // course department 
        int year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]); // course year

        //Convert to a data instance and add to the arrayList
        memFile.add(new Data(registration, title, department, year));
      }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.err.println("Found badly formatted line: " + readLine);
      }
    }
    inFile.close();

    //Sort according to the correct field 
    Collections.sort(memFile, new Comparator<Data>(){
      public int compare(Data d1, Data d2){
        switch(column){
          case 0: return d1.crns - d2.crns;
          case 1: return d1.name.compareTo(d2.name);
          case 2: return d1.department.compareTo(d2.department);
          case 3: return d1.year - d2.year;
          default: return 0;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

If you're doing this for learning, then you should expand upon this by making the `Data` class better. Such as:

- Add a constructor `public Data(String line)` that does the parsing to fields internally, throwing exceptions when needed. Then you can just pass the read line into the constructor
- Add equals and hashcode methods that work for the Data class. Hint - use Objects.equals and Objects.hashcode for easy implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Try TreeMap

```
TreeMap<String, String> treemap = new TreeMap<>();

private void insertSortedOn(String line, int fieldIndex){
    String[] tokens = line.trim().split(",");
    treemap.put(tokens[fieldIndex], line);
}
```

You could actually keep a different TreeMap for every "element".  It sorts based on whatever you use as the key.  Since your elements are always 4 you could have 4 `TreeMap`s using exactly the right types for each key.  Since they only hold references there wont be much memory duplication.